# When I resize my window below 700px, the dropdown animation transition goes off; how do I block this animation from happening upon resizing window?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a navigation bar that has a logo and a burgerbar that changes from a burger bar to an "x" when opened.

The problem is that the dropdown should go down when you click on the burger and go back up when you press the "x". This functions smoothly and perfectly so far, but the problem I noticed is that when I resize the browser window from >700px to <700px, the dropdown menu animation going up occurs.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { BurgerBar } from "../../styles/Navbar.style";
import Navlinks from "./Navlinks";

function Burger() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

    const prevWidth = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        prevWidth.current = width;
    }, [width]);
    function checkResize() {
        setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        if (prevWidth.current <= 700 && width > 700) {
            setOpen(false);
        };
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", checkResize);

    return (
        <>
            <BurgerBar open={open} onClick={() => {setOpen(!open);}}>
                <span />
                <span />
                <span />
            </BurgerBar>
            <Navlinks open={open} />
        </>
    )
};

export default Burger;
```

This is my styled-components file with the relevant styles:

```js
export const BurgerBar = styled.span`
    z-index: 1;
    width: 2rem;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: column;

    top: ${({open}) => open ? 22 : 24}px;
    height: ${({open}) => open ? 2.3 : 2}rem;
    right: ${({open}) => open ? 17 : 20}px;

    span {
        width: 2rem;
        height: 0.25rem;
        background-color: rgb(46, 203, 64);
        border-radius: 10px;
        transform-origin: 1px;

        &:nth-child(1) {
            transform: ${({open}) => open ? 'rotate(45deg)' : 'rotate(0)'};
            width: ${({open}) => open ? 2.3 : 2}rem;
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
            transform: ${({open}) => open ? 'translateX(100%)' : 'translateX(0)'};
            opacity: ${({open}) => open ? 0 : 1};
        }

        &:nth-child(3) {
            transform: ${({open}) => open ? 'rotate(-45deg)' : 'rotate(0)'};
            width: ${({open}) => open ? 2.3 : 2}rem;
        }
    }

    &:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 701px) {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
`;

export const Dropdown = styled.ul`
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;

    li {
        padding: 20px 20px;
        &:hover {
            opacity: 0.7;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 0;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        background-color: rgb(32, 80, 36);
        transform: ${({ open }) => (open) ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100%)'};
        vertical-align: middle;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
        top: 85px;
        align-items: center;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4%;
        li {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 4px;
        }
    }
`;
```

I recognize that the problem lies in these two lines:

`transform: ${({ open }) => (open) ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100%)'};`
and
`transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;`

I'm new to Javascript and React though and I cannot think of an efficient way to block the transition animation from going off upon browser resizing.

I can link my repo if more code/reference is necessary.

Comment: Your animation goes off because you are updating your state on resize so your component re-renders. Try to check what is the initial value of open when you re-render. Also as a note your function is very inefficient and it will cause a lot of unnecessary re-renders. you should only setWidth to a new window.innerwidth after the condition has been fulfilled. as you are doing it you are causing react to re-render the component on every single step of a resize instead of just where you need it.

Comment: @HogasAndreiMarius thank you for the suggestions. As for re-rendering the resize component only when I need it, do you have any guidances, direction for how I might implement this? Whenever I googled this problem, people seemed to always use the window.addEventListener("resize") option so I didn't know there are other standard ways to handle this. Also, I don't see why it is relevant what the initial value of open is when I re-render as whether "open" is false or true, both will result in a translation. Which means that if it's false, it will animate, and if it is true, it will also animate.